# Stanford Text Classifier Feature Selection

Tags: stanford-nlp, text-classification

I couldn't find any information about the feature selection mechanism in the stanford nlp text classifier.

Does the ColumnDataClassifier performs any feature selection by default. Following line is from the output for 20 news group data.

`numFeatures (Phi(X) types): 245343 [CLASS, 2-SW-et, 2-SW-stop, 2-SW-somebody, 2-SW-organizating, ...]`

With 245343 features I don't think it is possible for this tool to be so fast and use memory less than 2G. When I try to train a model on WEKA with the same data set but less features (45000), WEKA uses 8G of memory and takes forever to train the model.

Read a set of training examples from a file, and return the data in a featurized form. If feature selection is asked for, the returned featurized form is after feature selection has been applied.

Stanford NLP